# How to precheck VueJs3 checkboxes if their value is in an array at page creation while v-model used on the input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, vuejs3, v-model

I am trying to precheck some checkboxes based on their value: if the userApp.id is found in another array, I want the checkbox checked on page creation. The condition is no problem to me, yet I can't manage to precheck the checkboxes...

I use v-model to push the userApp.id in an array that will get in a POST body. I read in the VueJs documentation that v-model neutralizes the value and checked attributes.

How can I get those checkboxes already checked if they are in my other array ? I tried to use JS with document.getElementById(`${userApp.id}`).checked = true, but it doesn't work.

view.vue

```
        <div v-for="userApp in userApps" :key="userApp">
            <div class="form-check">                
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :value="userApp.id" :name="userApp.label" :id="userApp.id" v-model="checkedApps">
                <label class="form-check-label" :for="userApp.id">{{userApp.label}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

With the data:

```
 data() {
    return {
         checkedApps: [],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I did not think enough about the two-side binding created by the v-model. In the created() hook, I tried to push the id of the application I found in both arrays with a array.find() :

```
this.userApps.forEach(userApp => {
    if(this.apps.find(item => item.id == userApp.appInstanceId)) {
      this.checkedApps.push(userApp.appInstanceId)
      console.log(this.checkedApps)
    }
  })
```

And job's done ! My app checkbox (which id is in both arrays) is checked on page creation, and when unchecked is withdrawn from the checkedApps array.
Hope it can help others.